# when editButtonItem clicked, no red delete icon shows

Tags: iphone, rightbarbuttonitem

I am writing an IPhone IM chat window now.

You know if the nagviationItem.rightBarItem in an UITableviewController is set to editButtonItem, you click the edit button then a red delete icon is shown to every single row,  [like shown here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/45412920@N03/4289764318/).

The problem is, I have a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController:

```
@interface ChatUIViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
    UITableView *table;
    UITextField *textField;
```

}

and i did same to set editButtonItem:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

}

when i click the edit button, the [red delete icon will not show](http://www.flickr.com/photos/45412920@N03/4289764364/).

How can I make the red delete icon shown in my ChatUIViewController?

Thanks in advance to anyone who might help.
Michael

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add the following method to your table view delegate class:

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing) {
        // you might disable other widgets here... (optional)
    } else {
        // re-enable disabled widgets (optional)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a zillion, it worked perfectly.
The solution leads another question:
Why the above code is not needed in a class that is UITableViewController class, but is needed in a class that subclasses the UIViewController?
My intuition tells me the UITableViewController class calls setEditing:animated: under the hood.

Comment: My opinion is that a table view is not necessarily the only editable view. By making it part of a view controller, one can pass editable calls to any subview (like a table view).